# connection.dispatcher.end() is disconnecting bot from voice channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making a music bot in discord.js and I am looking for a way to call finish without the song ending when a user types !skip. The code I have right now is `connection.dispatcher.end();` but this seems to make the bot disconnect from the voice channel, if anyone could help that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the issue by just using `queue.songs.shift()` to remove the current song from the queue, then called my `play(queue.songs[0])` function.